# cxf interceptor intercept the request, but i can not find out the request params in the message

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, interceptor

My native language is not English and my English is poor,so I apologize if anything isn't clear.
I have searched, but it did not help.
I have a web service using cxf framework, I want to use an interceptor to intercept the request which is passed by the service invoker. I can intercept the request but I can`t find out the request params.

1. Here is my service interface:

   ```
   public int modCredenceForUser(@WebParam(name = "operatorId", mode = WebParam.Mode.IN) String operatorId,
                                     @WebParam(name = "userCredenceVO", mode = WebParam.Mode.IN) Holder<UserCredenceVO> userCredenceVO,
                                     @WebParam(name = "res", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT) Holder<Response> res)
   ```
2. Here is part of my service invoker code:

   ```
       userCredenceVO = new UserCredenceVO();
       ......
       ......
       Holder<UserCredenceVO> userCredenceVOHolder = new Holder<UserCredenceVO>(userCredenceVO);
       String operatorId = ServiceInvokeUtil.getOperatorId();
       int result = service.modCredenceForUser(operatorId, userCredenceVOHolder, res);
   ```
3. Here is part of my service provider code:

   ```
   public class AuthenticationInterceptor extends
           AbstractPhaseInterceptor {
       public AuthenticationInterceptor(){
           super(Phase.RECEIVE);
       }
       /*
       @Override
       public void handleFault(Message message) {
           super.handleFault(message);
       }
       */
       public void handleMessage(Message message) {
           ......
           ......
       }

   }
   ```

I want to find out the request param "userCredenceVO", but how could I find it inthe message.
This problem confused me a day, any help I would appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had been solved, the right codes as follows:

```
public class AuthenticationInterceptor extends
        AbstractPhaseInterceptor<SoapMessage> {

    public AuthenticationInterceptor(){
        super(Phase.PRE_INVOKE);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleFault(SoapMessage message) {
        super.handleFault(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
        Set _set = message.getContentFormats();
        Iterator classIterator = _set.iterator();
        while (classIterator.hasNext()) {
            Class _class = (Class) classIterator.next();
            Object _obj = message.getContent(_class);
        }    
    }

}
```

The _obj contains the request params which is passed by service invoker.